# Best performance: Windows 10 software striping vs. storage spaces simple

Tags: windows-10, software-raid, storage-spaces

Looking to squeeze a bit more speed out of my development PC for test VMs without necessarily switching to hardware RAID. I've got two identical 2TB SATA-3 data drives (OS is on SSD) so I could rebuild as a Windows 10 striped disk (using disk manager) or create a Windows 10 storage pool with a simple space.

Any suggestions for which would give the best performance? I've always understood that Windows software RAID was pretty poor (although probably better than non-striped) but that was compared to hardware RAID. Can't find much which compares software RAID to storage spaces.

Comment: And yes, it's all backed up so not overly worried about the inherent risks with RAID-0

Comment: What inherent risks do you believe exists with RAID 0?  You understand that Windows cannot be installed on a Storage Space right?  "I've always understood that Windows software RAID was pretty poor" You have miss inderstood, software RAID performance, on Windows is fine,

Comment: That there is no redundancy from disk failure

Comment: You have quoted me out of context - I said "software RAID was pretty poor compared to hardware RAID". I have since found this post which has the line "Windows software RAID has a bad reputation, performance wise, and even Storage Space seems not too different" http://serverfault.com/questions/685289/software-vs-hardware-raid-performance-and-cache-usage

Comment: It's not different because it's basically RAID 0/1/01 replacement

Answer (score 10):

#### Performance of single HDD

- this is just our base performance of single drive

[image: single]

---

#### Striped dynamic disk over 3 HDDs

- this what you call Windows software RAID

[image]

#### 3-column simple Storage Space over the same 3 HDDs

- this is adhoc storage space I made for you with `$spaceDisk = New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName $spaceName -StoragePoolFriendlyName $poolName -NumberOfColumns 3 -NumberOfDataCopies 1 -ResiliencySettingName Simple -ProvisioningType Thin -Size $spaceSize`
- the `-NumberOfColumns 3` controls the performance

[image: 3column]

---

In both test I used three 3 TB Toshiba HDDs ([DT01ACA300](http://storage.toshiba.com/docs/product-datasheets/dt01aca.pdf)). The Storage Spaces have bad reputation when it comes to performance, but that is mainly because of really poor performance of [parity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rUqG.png) Storage Space. Striping looks fine as you see.

Note that this is very bad benchmark, it is obvious that Windows cache kicked in for *sequential read* as there is no way that the 3 disks would attain 1100 MB/s for read. But you can take this numbers and compare them directly to this [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1DAC.jpg).